# Does C3PO know he has had his memory wiped?

Tags: star-wars

In [*Star Wars Episode 4: A New Hope*](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html), C3PO says that his first job was programming binary load lifters.

> **THREEPIO** Vaporators! Sir -- My first job was  programming binary load lifter... very similar to your vaporators. You could say...

Since he had his memory wiped at the end of *Star Wars Episode 3: The Revenge Of The Sith*, we know that this may or may not be entirely true, as he only remembers events after the end of The Clone Wars.

**Does C3PO even know that his memory has been wiped?**

(Anything from C-Canon and up will be accepted here.)

Comment: It's quite possible that memory wipe didn't remove necessary drivers/programs for binary load lifter interfaces. Meaning he could infer his first job without having a memory.

Comment: He knows he just doesnt remember

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Threepio claims in the novel *The New Rebellion* to have never had a memory wipe. He's also pathologically terrified of them in the same novel. So no, he doesn't seem to know that he underwent a memory wipe. This, of course, may well be ret-conned later, but as of now he doesn't realise he has had at least one memory wipe.

Funnily enough, when searching for the quote from *The New Rebellion*, [another answer by myself is the first result on Google](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39744/droid-memory-wipe). Couldn't find the quote though. He also claims to be over one hundred years old. This novel was written before the prequel films, so that has definitely been contradicted, so the other information may also have been so.

Comment: It's possible that some of C3PO's components were over one hundred years old. Who knows how they got to Anakin's workbench?